# BLOB/TEXT column 'number' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI3Ib.png)

**1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'number' used in key specification without a key length.**

Need help.

````
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paradox_serial_number` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identifier` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `number` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number` (`number`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;```
````

Comment: Question is unclear. You could have googled the error message to find out what it means. -1 for lack of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an index key is limited. From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html):

> The index key prefix length limit is 3072 bytes for `InnoDB` tables that
> use [`DYNAMIC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_dynamic_row_format) or [`COMPRESSED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_compressed_row_format) row format.
>
> The index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes for `InnoDB` tables that
> use the [`REDUNDANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_redundant_row_format) or [`COMPACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_compact_row_format) row format. For example, you might hit
> this limit with a [column prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_column_prefix) index of more than 191 characters on a
> `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` column, assuming a `utf8mb4` character set and the
> maximum of 4 bytes for each character.
>
> Attempting to use an index key prefix length that exceeds the limit
> returns an error.
>
> If you reduce the `InnoDB` [page size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_page_size) to 8KB or 4KB by specifying the
> [`innodb_page_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size) option when creating the MySQL instance, the maximum
> length of the index key is lowered proportionally, based on the limit
> of 3072 bytes for a 16KB page size. That is, the maximum index key
> length is 1536 bytes when the page size is 8KB, and 768 bytes when the
> page size is 4KB.

Find out which limit applies to your setup and specify that length when creating the index by postfixing the column name with that number in parenthesis. For example if 767 applies:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
             (...
              number longtext
                     NOT NULL,
              ...
              UNIQUE KEY number
                         (number(767))
                         USING HASH
              ...) ENGINE=InnoDB ...;
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paradox_serial_number` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identifier` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `number` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number` (number(767)) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;